# Can a suspension resolve by step in 16th notes?

Tags: nonchord-tones

Here is an example of what I mean.

[image: suspension resolving into a series of descending 16th notes]

The "suspension" is prepared, restruck and 9 does go to 8 but the 8 is a passing 16th note so I don't know of this counts as resolving the suspension since it keeps moving. Would this be considered a suspension or some other kind of accented non-chord tone?

Answer (score 2):

The duration of pitches is immaterial. The suspension in the example shown does resolve down by step even though the note of resolution is a 16th note and even though it immediately moves to another pitch.